# Get payload data from FCM Message when app is in the background

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to get the payload data from a fcm message, while my app is in the background. So I read this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#receive_and_handle_topic_messages) and they say,
I can get the data in the extras of the intent from my launcher activity, because if you click on the notification by default your launcher activity will open.

I send the message via the firebase console, then my app is in the foreground, I can handle all this via the onMessageReceived() method.

This is my code to achieve this, but the intent extras are null..

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
 bundleFCM = getIntent().getExtras();

 for (String key : bundleFCM.keySet()) {
 Log.d(TAG, "payload keys: " + key);
 }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to describe how you are sending the message.

Comment: I sending the message via firebase console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay my problem was, that I have a SplashActivity and the data payload was sent to this activity, so I transfer the data from the SplashActivity to my HomeActivity and all works fine.

Comment: I only have an Activity which is MainActivity, but the intent extras are null in 'onStart' function.